# Would someone mind just getting me started with my Russian homework?

Tags: грамматика

I have just started learning Russian (not getting a qualification, just for self interest). I have been set Задание 32 in the Поехали! Textbook 1. But my teacher is busy this week, and so cannot get me started.

The exercise starts as follows, and I do not know how to proceed, I’d appreciate some pointers:

```
Example answer:  
Это (я) дом. -- это мой дом.  
Это (я) дома. -- это мой дома.  

Questions:
1) Это (я) друзья. Ты их помнишь?  
2) Это (я) друг. Ты его помнишь?  
3) ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Это я дома" - "That's me at my home"

Comment: **my** isn't necessary, it's implied that the home is that of the speaker

Comment: this is not a site where someone will work on your home assignment

Comment: @shabunc Wrong dude! People did, and it was helpful. And it's just for my own interest, not an official qualification. So, I don't think that there's any harm whatsoever.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка interesting, thanks.

Comment: @NeilClay well, I just wanted to give you a sense of what is on-topic and off-topic here. People here a very helpful indeed, also first-time questions are always something we tend not to close unless we just don't have another option. Keep in mind that in general homework assignments do not belong here.

Comment: @shabunc We're just going to have to disagree here. I've used StackExchange sites for a decade, so I've seen thousands of "off-topic" arguments played out in threads. 

In this case all I was doing was asking a question about grammar as a complete novice who is not at school, college or university, and is not pursuing a formal qualification. I'm just taking a few Skype lessons and my tutor was busy. With my question answered I managed to make more progress during that weekend than I would have otherwise.

I take your point about “first-time questions” – I will bear that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide me a link to any on-topic homework question on a language stack.

Comment: to make it on-topic the question could have been worded differently, in particular without references to specific exercises in textbooks or elsewhere, although this may sound hypocritical and as an encouragement to act slyly, that's the way to stay within the rules limits

Comment: The beatings will continue until morale improves.

Comment: I'm sorry that the word "homework" has triggered you guys. Many thanks Yellow Sky and VaNdal.

Answer (score 9):

You seem to have a typo in the "Examples" section: instead of

> Это (я) дома. -- это мо**й** дома.

there should be

> Это (я) дома. -- это мо**и** дома.

The task is to put the pronoun in brackets into its possessive form, choosing the correct gender and number. In question 1) you do it like this: (я) > мои, 1st p. singular, the possessed object plural, because друзья (the possessed object) is plural.

**UPD:** I've had a look at the actual textbook you're studying. The words there have stresses marked, so "и́" (stressed и) may have seemed for you to be "й", but it's not so. Don't mix up the two things, in everyday Russian texts stresses are not marked.

[image]

Comment: the student's work done for him

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка - Far from that. Our SE is aimed at helping in learning. It would be injust to deny a person in pointing to a mistake on September 1. Especially at such a basic level, it is important to avoid delusions like that.

Comment: Great, many thanks for the help @YellowSky . I'll now crack on with the questions that I didn't post. Cheers!

Comment: Just a funny note. "Это мой дома" is a valid sentence in spoken Russian, but with the stress on first syllable in "дома." This means "It's my husband/boyfriend/son at home."